# Not able to list all spaces for domain using Google Chat API using App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, google-workspace

I have written below code to list all the Chat spaces in my domain. However when i run the code in AppScript it just gives me 'null' result. There is already ~100 Spacers in domain.

Below is the code i am using

```
function myFunction() {
  var user = "abc@xyz.com" // mention the user email id here
  var service = getOAuthService(user) // Gets the OAuth services for the user
  service.reset()
  if (service.hasAccess()) {
    var url = 'https://chat.googleapis.com/v1/spaces'
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
      headers: {
        Method : 'GET',
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + service.getAccessToken(),
      }
    });
    var spaceList = JSON.parse(response.getContentText()).spaces
  }
  Logger.log(spaceList)
}
```

Expecting to get the list of the chat spaces in response.